# Problem with VIM

Tags: vim, gvim

I have a problem with VIM on Ubuntu 10.4. It appears after I install gvim and do some configuring.
When I type the command Vim, the message below appears:

**Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
Segmentation fault**

I've surfed around, but I can't find solution to fix it. Please help me out if you have seen this.

Comment: Vim is also the tool for development

Comment: Try to launch `gvim -u none -U none` from the command line, it will start gvim without using your config files. If it works it is an issue with one of your config option.

Comment: @Xavier T: No command script should ever cause vim to crash with segfault.

Comment: @Jan Hudec : you are probably right but since it seems problems happened after some configuring, it would not harm to try at least once...

Comment: Did you check the requirements of your plugins? Maybe an interpreter (ruby, python…) is lacking.

Comment: after I ... *“do some configuring”*. What does it mean? Also try `unalias vim` and tell us what `which vim` says. Maybe colleagues are pranking you.

Comment: I run the gvim -u none -U none, it starts gvim properly.
So it must be my
 config and plugin problem, is there any command to fully remove all related vim plugIn and config or reinstall vim or gvim?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you just file a [bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an:

```
sudo apt-get purge vim
```

then delete your `~/.vim` directory and `~/.vimrc` (make backups first!)

This essentially will wipe your machine of vim.

Then, you can go about reinstalling vim (`sudo apt-get install vim`). However, this time before sure as you make modifications and add plugins, you restart `vim` after every added plugin or modification. If you run across the modification that causes your crash, file a bug report as [Jan Hudec suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919920/problem-with-vim/4920191#4920191).

This process will allow you to isolate what addon is causing your crash so that you can leave it out of your setup.

Comment: `apt-get purge` does not wipe files in users' home folders.

Comment: That is why I suggest deleting your `~/.vim` directory and `~/.vimrc` immediately after the `sudo apt-get purge vim`.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I totally misread your answer. I thought "then" said "this will".

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remove my downvote until the answer is edited. :(

Comment: It's ok, I'm not worried about points, just helping people.

Comment: Okay, but if you make some facile edit, I can remove it. And more rep means you can help people more easily. :)